# Matching a literal asterisk (*) in a regexp

Tags: regular-expressions

I am trying to write a regexp to mean:

At least one of a few punctuation marks followed by any number of blank spaces followed by a literal star is to be replaced by all those punctuation marks followed by a literal star.

So, when doing interactively,

`\([.,?!:;]+\)[[:blank:]]*\*` is replaced by `\1*`

But in elisp, I am not able to get the literal star. I tried:

`\\(\[\.,;:?।\]\+\\)\[\[:blank:\]\]\*\\*` to be replaced by `\\1\\*`

But it does not work.

Will you please point what is wrong? I think I am not escaping the literal star correctly. But I am not able to see what is the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

The correct string is `"\\([.,?!:;]+\\)[[:blank:]]*\\*"`.

Here's trick: evaluate `(read-string "regexp: ")`, enter your regexp, and look at the result.

If you use [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm), [`helm-regexp`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Regexp) is a great tool for exploring regexps, then converting them to strings via the `Kill regexp as sexp` action.